# Simplest way to generate unique Id onto a value grabbed from a form (React)

Tags: reactjs, forms, state

I'm trying to grab the value from the input, assign to it a unique id, then pass the name and the id to the addFolder() function. Then the object will be pushed onto the end of the state's folders array. My main issue is trying to create a unique id

```
    state = {
        name: '',
        id: ''
    }

    static contextType = Context;

    handleChange = (e) => {
        this.setState({name: e.target.value, id: ?? })  <-----------
    }

    handleSubmit = (e) => {
        e.preventDefault();
        this.context.addFolder(this.state.name, this.state.id)
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div>
            <form 
            className='AddFolderForm'
            onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}
            >
                <h2>Add Folder</h2>
                <label >Name: </label>
                <input 
                type="text"
                id=??            <------------------
                placeholder="Folder Name"
                value={this.state.name}
                onChange={this.handleChange}
                />
                <button
                    type="submit"
                >Submit

                </button>
            </form>
            </div>
        )
    }
}


export default AddFolder
```

```
class App extends Component {
    state = {
        notes: [],
        folders: [],
    };

.... other code...

addFolder = (name, id) => {
        this.setState(prevState => ({
            folders: [...prevState.folders, {
                "name": `${name}`,
                "id": `${id}`,
            }]
          }))
    }
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should check this library [uuid](https://www.npmjs.com/package/uuid) for react to generate unique id.
You have 5 versions to generate it.

`npm install uuid --save`

```js
import { v1 as uuidv1 } from 'uuid';

//This is your unique id
const id = uuidv1();
```

Comment: It's an overkill to use `uuid` for element id, it can cause (likely minor, depends size of the page and how many times it's used) perf issues and you don't need universal uniqueness, but just unique for the current webpage.

Answer (score 2):

There is a simple way in Vanilla js. If you use this method you don't need to add any dependencies which improve your project performance.

```
let uniqueId = (function () {
    let num = 0;
    return function (prefix) {
        prefix = String(prefix) || '';
        num += 1;
        return prefix + num;
    }
}
    ());
let id = uniqueId('id_');
console.log(id); // 'id_1'
```

There is an another method in lodash. 
add lodash by using the following command

```
npm i --save lodash
```

then use like the below example

```
let _ = require('lodash');

let id = _.uniqueId('id_');

console.log(id); // 'id_1'

let i = 10, ids = [];
while (i--) {
    ids.push(_.uniqueId('id_'));
}

console.log(ids[0]); // id_2
console.log(ids[9]); // id_11
```

If you need your Id in a different format Then follow the following way. It is also an advanced Vanilla js solution.

```
let uniqueId = (function () {
    let c = 0,
    st = new Date();
    return function (prefix) {
        var t = new Date() - st,
        r = Math.floor(Math.random() * 1000),
        str;
        prefix = String(prefix) || '';
        str = '-' + c + '-' + t + '-' + r;
        c += 1;
        return prefix + str;
    }
}
    ());

console.log(uniqueId('id'));
console.log(uniqueId('id'));
console.log(uniqueId('id'));
setTimeout(function () {
    console.log(uniqueId('id'));
}, 1000);
/*
id-0-1-145
id-1-8-113
id-2-9-598
id-3-1018-910
*/
```